# How to use text ads on admob, programmatically?

Tags: android, admob, banner

Short question:

I wish to be able to show only text ads using admob on some cases programmatically.

Is it possible? or is it completely random?

Comment: Did you test my solution below?

Comment: no i haven't. weird that i didn't remember seeing a notification from SO about your answer. i will check it out soon. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Just follow these steps:

1. Login to your admob account
2. Select "Manage Settings" for your ad
3. Select "Ad filters"
4. Select "Category / Type Settings"
5. Disable "Image Ads" at the bottom of the page

Comment: but can i do it at runtime?

Comment: I don't think so... but you can have two ads, one with images and another without images, then during runtime you decide and show accordingly...

Comment: hmmm... this might actually work. how do i have 2 different configurations? i'm quite a newb at this...

Comment: Create two different ads on your AdMob dashboard, then you will have two different IDs. After that you can configure one with images and the other without images.

Comment: thanks. will soon check it out. for now, i will tick your answer .

Comment: how can i create another ad? do you mean to create a new one with a new "Publisher ID" ?

Comment: Yes, you should get a new publisher id: http://www.admob.com/my_sites/create_site

Comment: too bad. i thought i will be able to create multiple ad types for the same app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. Why do you want to only show text ads, to reduce download usage?

Comment: yes, and also allow the user to not get too distracted by images/animations from the banner. i want to be nice... :)